# Go to any file in Light Table

Tags: lighttable

In Sublime Text you can go to any file using `ctrl+p` and entering a file name.  Is there a similar functionality in Light Table?  I understand how to edit user keymap; just couldn't find the relevant command.

Answer (score 7):

In Lighttable, typing `ctrl-o` will give you a similar file "fuzzy finder" that searches all file names and paths in your current workspaces.

It's surprising that the command doesn't show up in the command fuzzy-finder. I found it by accident when I reflexively tried the `ctrl-o` vim keystroke!

---

There is also the option of the ["Claire" plugin](https://github.com/joshuafcole/claire), which implements a file fuzzy finder inspired by emacs ido-mode.

Comment: just for the record:
The "file finder" does appear in the command's sidebar. The "problem" is that it is under the `Navigate: open navigate`  name.
This is due to it being able to search both files and directories